# Determine that a series is rational

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Determine whether $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/10^{n!} $$ is rational. I have tried thinking about decimal representations such as that of $1/11$, and the fact that this sum is equal to $0.1100010....1...........1$ etc, but I don't know if the distance between $1$'s increases fast enough (or if it even matters) for this to converge to a rational number.

Comment: See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesConstant.html, the archetypal example of a transcendantal number.

Comment: This was homework from some old university website, I am not sure what they had in mind. Is there some simple solution do you think other than citing Liouville?

Comment: Do the digits in this number have a repeating pattern ? Try to prove that your number has an aperiodic decimal expansion

Comment: What you deleted was correct : given a sequence $a_1...a_n$ where $a_i=0,1$, at rank $n$, your number will have $n!$ $0$'s, which means that $a_1...a_n$ does not appear in that section longer than $n$.

Comment: For any sequence $A$ in the expansion you can choose the $n,m$ such that $(a_{n},...,a_{m})$ has more zeroes than $A$. Thus no sequence is repeated indefinitely. What about that? Edit: Ok, thank you. I deleted it because it could be a clearer. As an example, if the sequence chosen is all zeroes, then $n,m$ must be chosen to find a $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sequence of digits is not quasi-periodic. Therefore, that number is irrational. There are many similar examples, such as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{10^{n^2}}$.

Comment: What does quasi-periodic mean?  eventually periodic?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner It means that it is periodic after a certain point, such as $0.123432323232\ldots$

Comment: For recreational purposes, let $$f(\sigma)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{10^{n^\sigma}}$$ Now what is the [Irrationality Measure](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) of $f(\sigma)$ ?